# How to implement search with contains using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, contains

I create a search query with Eloquent like this:

```
User::where('firstName', 'like', '%' . $search_value . '%')
      ->orWhere('lastName', 'like', '%' . $search_value . '%')
      ->get();
```

It's work. But I need to search with contains. For examle, if my search value is `hello world`, I should find row with value `World! Okay, hello`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use Laravel Macro and create a Macro to do exactly what you need. Checkout https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the easiest way to achieve this is to use Eloquent Macros:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// ...

Builder::macro('whereLike', function(string $attribute, string $searchTerm) {
   return $this->orWhere($attribute, 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%");
});
```

Now you can search Model like:

```php
User::query()
   ->whereLike('name', $searchTerm)
   ->whereLike('email', $searchTerm)
   ->get();
```

More on the subject on: https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel
and
https://tighten.co/blog/the-magic-of-laravel-macros

Answer (score 3):

1) You could create search trait with scope method.

**App\Traits\Searchable.php:**

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Searchable
{
    public function scopeSearch($builder, $query, $columns = null)
    {
        if($query){
            $words = explode(' ', $query);
            $words = array_filter($words);

            if(!$columns){
                $columns = $this->searchable;
            }

            $builder->where(function ($builder) use ($words, $columns) {
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $builder->where(function ($builder) use ($word, $columns) {
                        foreach ($columns as $column) {
                            if (strpos($column, '.') !== false) {
                                [$relation, $column] = explode('.', $column);
                                $builder->orWhereHas($relation, function ($query) use ($column, $word) {
                                    $query->where($column, 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                                });
                            } else {
                                $builder->oRwhere($this->getTable() . '.' . $column, 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

2) Add `Searchable` trait to model and `$searchable` property with searchable columns.

**App\Model\User.php:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Searchable;

    public $searchable = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
```

3) Use search scope:

```
$users = User::search($search_value)->get();
```

or with a specific columns:

```
$users = User::search($search_value, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'role.title'])->get();
```

Now you can use this trait with all your models and search trough model columns and model relations columns.

First argument accepts query, second argument accepts columns or relation columns with dottes (`relation.column`).

We split query to words and search all words matches in different columns.